# memory management in image display

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, image, memory-management

I have an `Image` object in a wpf application. The source is changed/set by a combobox which has several options. As you change option in combobox, source changes and you see different images.

Right now, I am making a list of bitmapimages and select images by  changing the index in the list. I dont know much about memory management, but I think when I make the `list<bitmapimage>` object, all the images remain in memory, but at a time I use only one image. So I have unnecessary data in memory.

My images are about 300x300 pixels and the size might increase in future applications (1000x1000 pixels). For now, the application is light enough, but I want to use efficient method to display images.

I want to know if is it a good idea to make list of images. Where are my files located when I make a `list` object? Is it better to create images, save them in a temporary location on hard disk and attach the source to these temp files.

I hope I am clear.

Comment: The images are created programatically before being added to the list? Can't you do that when the selected image has changed?

Comment: yes. Images are created programmatically and I thought of making a new image every time I change selection, but an array of 1000x1000 entries, it wont be an efficient approach, as far as i think. i can try and see.

Comment: And how many different images do you have in total?

Comment: i have about 10 images. So i have 1000x1000= 1 Mil pixel per image. one pixel is 4 bytes (?? I am not sure). that makes my image about 4 MB x 10 files = 40 MB in memory.

Comment: And would 40 MB additional memory consumption be a problem for the platform your application is running on? If not, you should just go ahead with your approach.

Comment: ehm.. not 40 MB, but future proof solution is a good approach i think

Answer (score 0):

Right now the size of your files in memory is not a problem (or are you developing on mobile?).
So you can persist your images and load them if needed.

Maybe you can create a buffer and/or queue for the data to improve your application.